# Table rows binding in angularJS

Tags: templates, angularjs

If I simplify my situation, I have a list of numbers which I want the user to be able to add to. They are being displayed as a list of HTML input boxes and I want there to be an extra, empty row at the bottom which will be added to the list as soon as it's used. Any ideas?

I've tried this, but obviously there's nothing linking the second include into the `numbers` array.

```
$scope.numbers = [1,1,2,3];
```

Which is displayed with:

```
<ul>
  <ng-include src="'row.html'" ng-repeat="number in numbers"></ng-include>
  <ng-include src="'row.html'"></ng-include>
</ul>

<script type="text/ng-template" "id="row.html">
  <li><input type="number" ng-model="number" /></li>
</script>
```

**EDIT**:

I don't know why I'm having a hard time explaining this :P I'm imagining 5 inputs for the data above, 4 containing the numbers above and a fifth which is empty (and potentially differently styled, eg. slightly transparent) As soon as a number is typed into the empty fifth input - say, the number 5 - then the list has an extra element so it reads `[1,1,2,3,5]` and there are now *6* inputs on the page, the last of which is empty and slightly transparent.

The aim is to allow people to be able to add a new row of data without there being an "add new row" button. Does that make sense?

Comment: you question is totally not clear kindly explain a little more and please  provide which version of angularjs you are using

Comment: Hopefully the additional text explains my full intention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure to understand the "as soon as it's used" but what can be easily achieved is to add an entry in the list as soon as the user hits enter on the last input. See below :

```
<ul>
  <ng-include src="'row.html'" ng-repeat="number in numbers"></ng-include>
</ul>
<form ng-submit="add()">
  <input type="number" ng-model="newNumber" />
</form>
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.numbers = [1,1,2,3];
$scope.newNumber = '';

$scope.add = function () {
    var parsed = parseInt($scope.newNumber);
    if(!isNaN(parsed)){
        $scope.numbers.push(parsed);
    }
    $scope.newNumber = '';
}
```

Every time the user will hit enter on the last input it will be added to the list of numbers and a new empty input will be shown at the bottom of the list.

A working Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnrdD/)

Comment: This is almost exactly, what I'm looking for, except I'd want it to `add()` the new number as soon as anything is entered, maybe I could `$watch` `$scope.newNumber` instead. I'm also going to have to play with the transferal from `newNumber` to `numbers`, as my actual need is for a whole row of data (not just one number), but this is pretty damned close!